# What's the right way to set routing for angular2 with koajs

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, koa, koa-router

I'm a newbie to angular2 and koajs. Maybe it's a silly question.

I have an angular2 app with a routing table as below:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pats/report/settings',
    component: PatsReportSettingsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'pats/report/:id',
    component: PatsReportComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'pats/report/login',
    component: PatsLoginComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '.',
    redirectTo: 'pats/report/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },      
  {
    path: '**',
    component: Pats404PageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];
```

If user access our app via the root url (http://localhost:3000), then navigate to a child page (eg: http://localhost:3000/pats/report/settings), everything is fine since angular2 app will deal with the child page navigation internally and will not issue a http request to backend.

But if user access our app with child page url directly, eg: http://localhost:3000/pats/report/settings, the backend koajs app will response with 404 status since it does not exist a route for path 'pats/report/settings' at the backend.

**What's the right way to resolve this problem?**

**Should I add route for all client child page paths in the backend router and respond with the index.html?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know Koajs, but you need some middleware. Your backend needs to redirect those request to `localhost:3000/` but let the URL as it is, so that angular can do its magic!

See this additional packages for koajs:

- [koa-repath](https://github.com/xsmallbird/koa-repath)
- [rewrite](https://github.com/koajs/rewrite)

The other option: Use Hashbang-URLs !
[Angular2 URL-Styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles)

Comment: Checked [Angular2 URL-Styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles), and it seems that Hashbang-URL is not recommended.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to show you that option too. Best practice would be the correct handling of `unknown URLs` via your koajs-backend.

Comment: I've tried koa-repath, it works well! Thanks again, @mxii